# How to get data from a callback url in an SPA?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, callbackurl

I am working on a React application and it makes an api call that sends updates to a callback url which I must define. I have two questions:

1. How do I create a callback url?
2. How do I get the data from that callback url if my application is front end only and it doesn't have a server to listen for requests?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't. You need a server that can receive the request, then you're front-end app will have to retrieve it (the data) from your server by polling, or websockets or some other means of communication.

Comment: Ah shoot, that's what I was afraid of. I'll look into those. Thank you!